# Is there a better way to use the jQuery UI widget factory without jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I develop and maintain a jQuery widget called [jquery-ui-picklist](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-picklist/). I've been wanting to remove the dependency on jQuery UI so that it can be used in both jQuery and jQuery UI apps alike.

I've avoided the transition, until yesterday, when I figured out I could simply do something like this:

```
(function($)
{
    if($.widget == null)
    {
        // Contents of jquery.ui.widget.js, straight from jQuery UI, goes here.
    }

    $.widget("awnry.pickList",
    {
        // My widget's actual code goes here.
    });
}(jQuery));
```

(If you're interested, the widget's full source [can be found here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-picklist/source/browse/tags/0.6.0/jquery-picklist.js).)

Needless to say it feels dirty and hacky to be including, verbatim, a vendor's code like this. Is there a more correct, elegant, or better way to drop the jQuery UI dependency without making my users add another JS include to their pages?

Comment: Sounds like you should keep the dependency on jQuery UI.

Comment: I would work through `$.fn` and completely remove the dependency. The widget factory really doesn't do much for you, it is just an easy way to solve some of the common issues that the plugins run into,  instance re-connection, data storage etc.. it's not hard to do those things for yourself... -ck

Comment: No reason to add the dependency back. (Or do you want to elaborate?) Only thing I'm using from jQuery UI is the widget factory, and that's available as a separate file. I'm considering offering two choices: use jQuery UI, or include the widget factory file.

I actually started this plugin with $.fn, and I ported a few months back. Certainly, the widget factory isn't necessary to make a plugin, but I don't see myself going back.

Comment: Why don't you create it as simple plugin without using jquery ui.

Comment: Why not just include jquery.ui.widget.js? https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js

Comment: @Andrew, I think that's what I'm leaning toward...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After considering my options, I ended up removing the `if()` statement and the Widget Factory code from my widget.

Users of my widget have two choices. If their page includes jQuery UI, nothing extra must be done. If their page includes only regular jQuery, `jquery.ui.widget.js` (which is packaged with my widget for convenience's sake) must also be included.

My reasons for making the decision:

- Widget code isn't cluttered up with vendor code.
- Widget is decoupled from any specific Widget Factory implementation or version. In other words, `$.Widget` can come from jQuery UI or `jquery.ui.widget.js` or wherever; the widget doesn't care.
- Widget still works with regular jQuery, yet I still benefit from using the Widget Factory.
- Upgrading the Widget Factory is simply a matter of dropping in a new file.